# Conditional formatting on numeric and date measure value

Tags: tableau-api

Is there a way to conditional format a measure value as date in some case and numeric in some cases? I have a measure value Max, however some measure are dates and some are numeric. If I convert everything to numeric I lose dates and viceversa. can we just select a single measure and define max of it as a date and for others as numeric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend on how your dates are formatted, but a date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format could be identified by the following calculated field.

```
IIF((FIND(ATTR([Max]), "/") > 0), 'Date', 'Number')
```

[image: Identifying numeric or date values using a calculated field]